# Can a VBA generated pdf name correspond to values within certain cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using VBA to generate an automated letter for me. Using the below:

```
Sub CreatePDF()
    Dim wSheet As Worksheet
    Dim vFile As Variant
    Dim sFile As String

    Set wSheet = ActiveSheet
    sFile = Replace(Replace(wSheet.Name, " ", ""), ".", "_") _
            & "_" _
            & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd\_hhmm") _
            & ".pdf"
    sFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sFile

    vFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
    (InitialFileName:=sFile, _
        FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
        Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

    If vFile <> "False" Then
    wSheet.Range("P1:Y336").ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=vFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

    MsgBox "PDF file has been created."
    End If
End Sub
```

Wondering if there is a way to make the generated file name of the PDF to correspond to specific cell inputs (in the sheet, they are pulled in by vlookup). Ideally, have the file be: C7_C8.pdf

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you mean the cell address, or what's inside the cell.

But i just hardcode the "sFile" to a specific cell in my worksheet :

```
sFile = Workbooks("blabla.xlsb").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AE14")
```

into the below, notice the `"" &`

```
vFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
    (InitialFileName:="" & sFile, _
        FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
        Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")
```

so whatever cell AE14 contains it will be passed as the PDF filename in the Save As prompt. hope it helps!